# How to interpret the D3 statement "var r = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range([5,1000])"?

Tags: d3.js

Using D3.js, how do I properly interpret the following statement, in English...

```
var r = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1]).range([5,1000])
```

I'm trying to clearly understand what the code means and does.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

My Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

r is equal to a linear scale with a domain of 0 to 1 and a range of 5 to 1000.

Or, a little less mathematically, r will be a function that changes values in the interval [0,1] to values in the interval [5,1000]. If you call r(0), it will return 5, and if you return r(1), it will return 1000. Linear means that equal magnitude changes in the arguments to the function are mapped to equal magnitude changes in the return value. That is,

```
r(0.1) - r(0.0) == r(0.9) - r(0.8)
```

Comment: So the range is the desired scale and the domain is what you're mapping to that desired scale?

Comment: I meant to say... so the range is the desired scale and the domain is what you're mapping to that desired scale?  Could it be reversed, where for example: "var r = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,1000]).range([5,100])",  where a broader absolute domain spread is mapped to a much smaller range scale?

Comment: Yeah, you could think of it that way. If you're rendering a graph, range would be the actual physical units along the axis and domain would be the units for the quantity.

Comment: And, yes, you can map a broad domain onto a small range. You can even reverse the numbers so that a higher input results in a smaller output.